# I'm getting an error java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory in S3 bucket, trying to access it from AWS EMR cluster

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, hadoop2, filenotfoundexception

I'm working on a standalone java application which is using Hadoop Map Reduce framework. I'm running this application on AWS EMR cluster and the input files are present in S3 bucket. I have not facing this issue for long but suddenly I'm getting this following error.

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory <S3_Bucket_Path>
```

When I checked, the files are present in the specific S3 bucket folder. If file is already present why is this giving FileNotFoundException.

I am using this below code to list all the objects present in the S3 bucket and storing the full path of these S3 objects into a `List<String> inputFilesList`

```
    List<S3ObjectBean> fullInputFilesS3ObjectBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(S3_BUCKET, prefix);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
    //To fetch more than 1000 files from AWS S3 bucket
    while(objectListing.isTruncated()) {
        objectListing = s3client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing); 
        objects.addAll(objectListing.getObjectSummaries());
    }
```

After getting the list of inputFiles I'm feeding thos to mapper in Hadoop MapReduce application. Code is given below.

```
private void setMapper(Job job, Class<? extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>> mapperClass, List<String> inputFilesList) {
    for (String inputFile : inputFilesList) { 
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputFile), TextInputFormat.class, mapperClass);
    } 
}
```

The variable List inputFilesList contains the data file full path S3 objects like "s3://bucket_name/folder/fileName1.txt", "s3://bucket_name/folder/fileName2.txt"

Comment: can you share the emr code to get s3 bucket file ?

Comment: The code is
`code`
private void setMapper(Job job, Class<? extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>> mapperClass, List<String> inputFilesList) {
    for (String inputFile : inputFilesList) {
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputFile), TextInputFormat.class, mapperClass);
    }
}
`code`
The variable List<String> inputFilesList contains the data file full path S3 objects like 
"s3://bucket_name/folder/fileName1.txt",
"s3://bucket_name/folder/fileName2.txt"

Comment: `code`
List<S3ObjectBean> fullInputFilesS3ObjectBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(S3_BUCKET, prefix);
List<S3ObjectSummary> objects = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();

//To fetch more than 1000 files from AWS S3 bucket
while (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
    objectListing = s3client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
    objects.addAll(objectListing.getObjectSummaries());
}
`code`